# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, identityserver4, docker-container

I got a problem setting up identityserver to my dotnet core application inside docker.

My problem is that identityserver is missing the 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0 from the required DLL. However it works well on my machine event from local containers.(Although I know windows and linux containers has a huge difference in every way).

Whenever the application misses the package I have to change something inside the code to trigger a new build from the source. After a few builds the application works just fine.(Althought I just added some comments to the application) Anybody knows on which side to investigate for this type of problem? Is that a bug in my code, docker, dotnet, etc?

My dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine AS build
COPY src /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /src/build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src/build .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "auth-service.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error occurred during the build phase since dotnet publish also does a restore to the project. I had to add --no-restore flag to get the right packages